# Understanding behaviour of removing element from set during iteration

Tags: python, for-loop, cpython

I am aware that we shouldn't modify collection while iterating over it, but that behaviour blew my mind - could someone explain why does it stop and what is happening under the hood in cpython? I tried to dissassembly **foo** function but got no answers at all. I am talking about

```
def foo(first):
    d = {0}
    for n, k in enumerate(d, first):
        d.remove(k)
        d.add(n)

    print(d)

foo(1)  # prints {8}
foo(6)  # prints {8}
foo(8)  # prints {10} on my macos and {8} on other user machine
foo(9)  # prints {16}
```

To explore what was happening, I added some print statements:

```py
def foo(first):
    d = {0}
    for n, k in enumerate(d, first):
        print("before update : dict =",d,"pos =",n,"ele =",k,end='\t')
        d.remove(k)
        d.add(n)
        print("after update : dict =",d,"pos =",n,"ele =",k)
    print(d)

foo(1)  
print("===========")
foo(6)  
print("===========")
foo(8)  
print("===========")
foo(9)
```

Results :

```
before update : dict = {0} pos = 1 ele = 0  after update : dict = {1} pos = 1 ele = 0
before update : dict = {1} pos = 2 ele = 1  after update : dict = {2} pos = 2 ele = 1
before update : dict = {2} pos = 3 ele = 2  after update : dict = {3} pos = 3 ele = 2
before update : dict = {3} pos = 4 ele = 3  after update : dict = {4} pos = 4 ele = 3
before update : dict = {4} pos = 5 ele = 4  after update : dict = {5} pos = 5 ele = 4
before update : dict = {5} pos = 6 ele = 5  after update : dict = {6} pos = 6 ele = 5
before update : dict = {6} pos = 7 ele = 6  after update : dict = {7} pos = 7 ele = 6
before update : dict = {7} pos = 8 ele = 7  after update : dict = {8} pos = 8 ele = 7
{8}
===========
before update : dict = {0} pos = 6 ele = 0  after update : dict = {6} pos = 6 ele = 0
before update : dict = {6} pos = 7 ele = 6  after update : dict = {7} pos = 7 ele = 6
before update : dict = {7} pos = 8 ele = 7  after update : dict = {8} pos = 8 ele = 7
{8}
===========
before update : dict = {0} pos = 8 ele = 0  after update : dict = {8} pos = 8 ele = 0
{8}
===========
before update : dict = {0} pos = 9 ele = 0  after update : dict = {9} pos = 9 ele = 0
before update : dict = {9} pos = 10 ele = 9 after update : dict = {10} pos = 10 ele = 9
before update : dict = {10} pos = 11 ele = 10   after update : dict = {11} pos = 11 ele = 10
before update : dict = {11} pos = 12 ele = 11   after update : dict = {12} pos = 12 ele = 11
before update : dict = {12} pos = 13 ele = 12   after update : dict = {13} pos = 13 ele = 12
before update : dict = {13} pos = 14 ele = 13   after update : dict = {14} pos = 14 ele = 13
before update : dict = {14} pos = 15 ele = 14   after update : dict = {15} pos = 15 ele = 14
before update : dict = {15} pos = 16 ele = 15   after update : dict = {16} pos = 16 ele = 15
{16}
```

Comment: the behaviour is implementation-dependent, you cannot rely on it

Comment: yeah, I know and I won't, but would like to understand that implementation detail in detail

Comment: *What* implementation detail? This goes through several layers down to a few dozen to hundred lines of C code. Which *part* of that are you wondering about?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi mostly what's magic behind 8 that it stops instead of going into infinite

Comment: I suspect this has to do with whether your new element being inserted hashes before or after the one that was there before in the inner representation of the set. The iterator has some kind of pointer into the set, iteration will stop as soon as that pointer is after the new element. What surprises me more is that `foo(1)` gets all the way to 8 before stopping.

Comment: You can get a small window into the innards of sets by printing some two element sets. `{6,7}` gets printed as is, but `{7,8}` gets printed as `{8,7}`, which would be consistent with my theory. On my computer, `for i in range(64): foo(i)` prints the next multiple of 8 for each i.

Answer (score 1):

An iterator into a set has to have some kind of pointer into the set, and iteration will stop as soon as that pointer is after the new element.

Playing around with small sets on my computer (Python 3.7 on Windows), I can get a sense of the order in which elements are hashed into the set.

```
>>> {6,7}
{6, 7}
>>> {7,8}
{8, 7}
>>> {8,9}
{8, 9}
```

Notice how the 8 got printed before the 7, but the others were increasing. The loop `for i in range(64): print({i, i+1})` in fact shows me that multiples of 8 always hashes both before their predecessor and successor, at least on my computer, but other pairs of consecutive ints stay in increasing order.

Of course, as has been pointed out, all this relies on implementation-specific details, but I think the principle I'm suggesting should hold in general, just by how one could efficiently implement iteration over sets.